# implode function but not for every single array element

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

I would like to use the implode function `implode(" ",$array);` but I do not want to have a space between every single array element. So for example if the array is `$array = array("M.","Benz","wants","to","marry","A.","Marry");` I do not want to have a space between `M.Benz` and `A.Marry`.

Comment: What's the rule then? When you want a space, and when you don't want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with your code as below if you only want to replace the space from `M.Benz` and `A.Marry`.

```
$array = array("M.","Benz","wants","to","marry","A.","Marry");
$str = implode(" ",$array);
echo $str = str_replace(". ", ".", $str);
```